# Searching for a word to pdf converter that will handle special fonts

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf

I have a 500-page Word document made in MS Office 2007. While making this file I have imported 487 types of fonts. However, now it is really tough to convert the file to pdf. I have tried various converters including the built-in Office 'save as' option. There were some converters which were able to convert the document, but only one page of it.

Can anyone link me to a free full version (not trialware) of a Word to PDF converter that can keep my imported fonts intact?

I have tried many, such as Word2PDF, PDFonline, and many others. [PDFCreator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/) converted my file with 70% accuracy, but I'm still looking for something better.

Comment: What converters have you tried? You're looking for some very specific requirements that it is unlikely others have tried exactly. Please update your question with a list of those converters you have tried so far so that we can perhaps list those you have not yet tried.

Comment: Have you tried to use Adobe Acrobat to convert them?  This is the reason you don't use hundreds of different fonts in a single document.

Comment: No i didn't get adobe acrobat for free...so i didn't took the risk

Comment: With whatever you use, see if there's an option of embedding the fonts in the file created (actually it only embeds a subset). Tha's what I do with documents that use non-standard fonts so they will look right on other people's systems who do have all the font's installed. To "convert" Word documents I then just print them to a PDF file using the Adobe PDF Creator virtual printer which came with the Acrobat Professional application I have.

Comment: Are you sure that all fonts you have used can be embedded into the PDF? Some fonts are marked as never embeddable because of copyright restrictions (and some can only be embedded partially). Therefore all legal products will not embed them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I don't use it very often, when needed I have found [PDFCreator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/) to be nearly flawless. Unless I am misunderstanding what you mean by "keep the fonts intact". In all my experiences the appearance has been identical.

Comment: yes i also tried that one but it just give 70% accuracy in fonts

Comment: Did you try the font options under the advance button in the printer properties?  The description here sounds promising http://tenser.typepad.com/tenser_said_the_tensor/2004/11/word_doc_to_pdf.html

Answer (score 1):

[CutePDF](http://www.cutepdf.com/Products/CutePDF/writer.asp) installs itself like a printer, and will "print" to a PDF file from just about anything. Not sure how it handles fonts, but personally I have never had a problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the [MS plugin](https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/save-a-file-in-pdf-format-HA010064992.aspx) to print the document to PDF? PDFCreator mentioned above is also a good option.

Comment: i have used MS-plugins but it gives error while conversion...and i don't want to print documents i just want to convert them

Comment: PDF files are encoded printer files. This is why the standard method of creating PDFs is "printing". To convert to PDF requires the computer to issue a print command to a virtual printer.

Answer (score 0):

OpenOffice and LibreOffice can open Word documents and export them as PDF, but I'm not sure how good they are at reading the Word format.